# django-cities: Could not find the GDAL library

Tags: django

I'm using `Django 2.0` and using [`django-cities`](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities) to import country and state data to the database.

I only want little information like, `country name`, `country code`, `currency code`, `currency symbol`, `currency name` and their associated states data like `state name` and `state code`.

It is quite difficult to have all data for all countries in the world.

After installing `django-cities`, the only changes I'm made is

1. added `cities` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. added this setting item in `app.settings.py`.
   `CITIES_INCLUDE_NUMERIC_ALTERNATIVE_NAMES = True`

When I run `manage.py migrate` it gives following error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL
>   library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0",
>   "gdal1.11.0", "gdal1.10.0", "gdal1.9.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is,
>   try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

Since I am not using any geographical data to plot on map, etc. I do not want to install `GDAL` on my system.

**How can I use this plugin to have only `country` and `state` data without creating a mess-up in database with data that is of no use to me?**

Comment: You can't - GeoDjango is a [requirement](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities#requirements) of the app.